# Magento 2: Create a url like : localhost/magento/{frontname}/profile/id/5

Tags: magento2, url

I want to create a url like `localhost/magento/{frontname}/profile/id/5'

so, i have created a controller file `profile.php`

```
namespace Learning\HelloPage\Controller;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Profile extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
    {
       parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * View  page action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */

    public function execute()
    {
       $seller_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

       $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);


       return $resultPage;
    } 
}
```

this is i have done so far and if i run this url : `localhost/magento/{frontname}/profile/id/5` it takes me to `404 page`
please suggest a solution.

Comment: What is question and issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create URL like `localhost/magento/{frontname}/profile/id/5`, you need to define the route front name in **app/code/Learning/HelloPage/etc/frontend/routes.xml** file.

Below is the syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="viewfile" frontName="viewfile">
            <module name="Learning_HelloPage" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Where you can define the front name under **frontName** parameter.

**Note:** I assume that you have already created module's basic skeleton, i.e.

- app/code/Learning/HelloPage/etc/module.xml
- app/code/Learning/HelloPage/registration.php

Comment: hi i have created the `routes.xml` file also but tell me how can i run this `localhost/magento/viewfile/profile/id/5` url

Comment: Please share the steps which you have done so far?

Comment: I think you have not run command:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade